# How do we square a random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

How do we square a random variable? For example, Let $Y=X^2$.

$$f_X(x)={\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}} \cdot e^{\tfrac{-x^2}{2}}$$

How do we derive $f_Y(y)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivative of $F(t)=P(Y<t)=P(X^2<t)=P(-\sqrt t<X<\sqrt t)$?

Comment: $$\eqalign{
  & {F_Y}(t) = P( - \sqrt t  < X < \sqrt t ) = {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\left[ {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{\sqrt t } {{e^{{{ - {x^2}} \over 2}}}} dx - \int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ - \sqrt t } {{e^{{{ - {x^2}} \over 2}}}} dx} \right]  \cr 
  & {{d{F_Y}(t)} \over {dt}} = {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\left[ {{e^{{{ - {t^2}} \over 2}}} \cdot {1 \over {2\sqrt t }} + {e^{{{ - {t^2}} \over 2}}} \cdot {1 \over {2\sqrt t }}} \right] = {1 \over {\sqrt {2t\pi } }}{e^{{{ - {t^2}} \over 2}}}  \cr 
  & {f_Y}(y) = {1 \over {\sqrt {y \cdot 2\pi } }}{e^{{{ - {y^2}} \over 2}}} \cr} $$

Comment: @TiloWiklund Is this right or am I just doing some non-sense?, Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you might have gotten integration limits or similar wrong (nothing you shouldn't be able to fix by just rereading what you did, could also just be me who's handicappted at computation :)), otherwise it looks reasonable.

Comment: this is right. Anyway this method is effective only for real r.v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $g$ a measurable bounded function.

$$
Eg(Y) = Eg(X^2) = \int_0^\infty g(x^2) f_X(x) dx 
+\int_{-\infty}^0 g(x^2) f_X(x) dx
\\
= \int_0^\infty g(y) f_X(\sqrt{y}) \frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}} +
\int_0^\infty g(y) f_X(-\sqrt{y}) \frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}} 
$$
hence $$
f_Y(y) = \frac 1{2\sqrt{y}}(f_X(-\sqrt{y}) + f_X(\sqrt{y})) 1_{y\ge 0}
$$